# Multiple array to test with mocha/chai/expect

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I'm doing several test with **mocha/chai**, but in this case I have no ideia what I have to do.

In this array *(for instance)*:

```
[ { rectangles: '1',
    rows: '1',
    cols: '1' },
  { rectangles: '1',
    rows: '2',
    cols: '1' },
  { rectangles: '4',
    rows: '2',
    cols: '2' } ]
```

And I would like to test if, for instance ...

```
array1 : rectangles = 1;
array2 : rectangles = 1;
array3 : rectangles = 4;
```

Is possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
        it('Should an for array data-rectangles 1,1,4', function(){
            var el = code.listGrids(gridSelector);
            expect(el[0]).to.own.include({rectangles: '1'})
            expect(el[1]).to.own.include({rectangles: '1'})
            expect(el[2]).to.own.include({rectangles: '4'})
        });
```

Super easy! =)